# PyQt5: Cannot create cross-platform QtWebKitWidget application

Tags: linux, windows, pyqt5, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I've developed a PyQt5 application on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) that uses a QtWebKitWidget (QtWebView). It works great on Linux. I'm trying to package it for distribution for Windows using cx_Freeze, but the resulting application stops execution at launch with the PyQt5 error message "Import Error: Cannot import name 'QtWebKitWidgets.'"

I read that QtWebKitWidgets was deprecated from PyQt5 as of Qt 5.6, and that I should now use QtWebEngineWidgets instead. Fair enough. But I can't seem to install QtWebEngineWidgets on Ubuntu. I've installed Qt Creator 5.10 (most recent as of Dec 2017), and tried to include QtWebEngine via the oinline installation wizard, but the QtWebView widget is not listed in the toolbox.

My question: how can I use a PyQt5 WebView widget that will be cross-platform?  If I use QtWebKit, it works on Linux but not on Windows. If I use QtWebEngine, it should work on Windows but not Linux.

What do I need to install on both platforms?

(Thanks in advance.)

Comment: Your conclusion is not correct, QtWebKit is only supported until Qt 5.5 on all platforms, from there it was replaced by Qt WebEngine. What probably happens with your application is that in linux you are using a version earlier than Qt 5.5 and in the case of windows a later version than qt5.6.

Comment: Also what happened with QtWebkit is that it has no support, it is not that it can not be installed in current versions of Qt or PyQt. for example I have installed QtWebkit and QtWebEngine in PyQt5 5.9 and also in Qt 5.10

Comment: I am using Qt 5.10 on Linux. QtWebView does not appear in Qt Creator's toolbox. How can I install it so that I can use it?  Or, alternatively, how can I install QtWebKit on Windows? (I can't find an installation file, etc.)  ((I should say that I used to be using 5.5 on Linux, but today installed 5.10 in hopes of fiinding Qt Creator updated to include QtWebEnginge. Instead, I don't find any QtWebView widget at all.)

Comment: What compiler are you using? Qt Webengine is not supported by MinGW

Comment: I'm not compiling (as far as I know). I'm using PyQt.  For creating the Windows .exe file, I'm using cx_Freeze.

Comment: Surely this version does not have it installed, download the source code and compile it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a try tomorrow.  I had hoped I was essentially getting the correct version for Ubuntu already when I used the Qt online downloader application.

Comment: Well, holy cow! In a moment of desperation, I tried reinstalling PyQt5 with the command `sudo -H pip3 install PyQt5` and then QtWebEngineWidgets could import and function perfectly. QWebView also now shows up in Qt Creator.  I'm baffled as to why, but I'm not complaining.

Comment: The Qt Web Engine doesn't use the same class names. QWebView becomes QWebEngineView. You can see the class documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html